# Schur decomposition of a "flipped" triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, schur-decomposition, triangularization

I would like to take a general 5 x 5 matrix which is a triangular matrix "upside down", i.e.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a\\
0 & 0 & 0 & b & c\\
0 & 0 & d & e & f \\
0 & g & h & i & j \\
m & n & o & p & q \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And convert it to a triangular matrix. By Schur's Theorem (the Schur Decomposition), there is a Unitary matrix $U$ so that $U^{*}AU$ is upper triangular. Mathematica doesn't want to do it with parameters, nor does it even want to do it if I put in integers (something about infinite precision). In any case, I really need the *unitary* matrix, as well as the triangular matrix that results.

What I am hoping for is this: Going back the other way, I hope that for such a unitary matrix $U$, that for *any* (5x5) triangular matrix $T$, $U^{*}TU$ is "upside-down triangular," even if the entries end up in different spots. Proving that would be enough, even if it can be proven abstractly without finding a form for $U$.

Comment: you may as well write out what Mathematica tells you the characteristic polynomial is... is there a reason you think said quintic has a closed form solution for its roots?

Comment: No, there isn't. You're right, the eigenvalue expressions that Mathematica gave are disgusting. My hope is simply for an argument that triangular matrices can be unitarily "flipped' into this form, even if the resulting entries are gross.

Answer (score 1):

There exists no unitary matrix $U$ such that for every triangular matrix $T$, $UTU^*$ is upside-down triangular.

To see this, it suffices to note that the identity matrix $I$ is triangular, but that $UIU^* = UU^* = I$ will fail to be upper-triangular for any unitary matrix $U$.